# Improve SQL queries reducing inner joins with In

Tags: sql, postgresql

I came across some legacy code in which they used two inner joins I replaced that with following .

```
 select p.id
 from publisher p 
    inner join retailer r on p.retailer_id = r.id
 where  p.id IN  (1,4,5 .... around 100 or more random ids I get from code) 
 order by case r.sector_id when r.sector_id then 1 else 2 end,
          p.seo_frontpage_factor asc,
          case (r.poi_sector_id) when r.poi_sector_id then 3 else 4 end,
          p.id asc
```

Previous query was like below.

```
select p.id
from publisher p 
   inner join retailer r on p.retailer_id = r.id
   inner join (select 1 as id union all select 2 ,union all select 3 ......) as x on p.id = x.id
   order by case r.sector_id when r.sector_id then 1 else 2 end,
           p.seo_frontpage_factor asc,
           case (r.poi_sector_id) when r.poi_sector_id then 3 else 4 end,
           p.id asc
```

My question is would  this be a good idea reducing inner joins to improve performance ?  If not what can I do optimise this or this is good as it is ?

Comment: [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/), [SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-reference) and [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org) are different software packages produced by different companies. Even if all of them implement SQL, they extend it in different ways and sometimes they use different syntax conventions that render the queries incompatible between them. Please use only the tags that match the software you are using.

Comment: Not enough information. However: if the set of included values for `p.id` is a set of consecutive numbers, then both ways above are a waste of effort. Just have something like `WHERE p.id > 0 AND p.id < 100...`

Comment: This particular change probably makes no difference to performance. Best bet is to see the execution plan before and after. It's certainly more readable after your change.

Comment: what else do you need @PeterAbolins the ids are not 1 ,2 ...100 they are random values

Comment: What else do I need? There is no schema, there is no information about what you need, and the queries are incomplete. It isn't even clear what RDBMS you are using. There is a query that looks highly inefficient and you rewrote it, but as @RomanStarkov says... your rewrite probably makes little to no difference to performance.

Comment: You say you want to improve the query, but what aspect do you want to improve? Performance? Maintainability? Readability? Actual output?

Comment: Having two joins should reduce performance right ?? @RomanStarkov

Comment: @HoneyBadger My goal is performance improvements see the updated question

Comment: If the ids are random values, then how do you construct the `IN` clause?

Comment: @PeterAbolins I get those ids from somewhere else  from the code not sql

Comment: @axiac updated the question tags

Comment: If your goal is performance, then check the execution plans You can display them using `explain (analyze, buffers) select ..`. For more details see: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html

Comment: Ok - I won't argue with secrecy. My point was that if there is a pattern to the IDs that you are interested in, then there could be a much easier way of constructing your query, rather than physically listing every ID that is of interest - regardless of whether it is in a massive `UNION ALL` subselect, or a massive `IN` statement.

Comment: Sometimes rewriting large `IN` queries to use an array makes a difference, e.g. `where p.id = any(array[1,2,...])`. Note that `join (select 1 as id union all select 2 ...) as ...` can be simplified to `join (values (1),(2), ..) as ...`)

Comment: As I said this is a legacy code .. There is no pattern for that matter :( . I get those from somewhere else :( . You can say from another service value now we can not avoid that .. @PeterAbolins and those ids were generated using code so thats not a hard thing to generate or code ..

Comment: Two joins are more expensive than one join, for sure, but don't forget that `in` - it could be cheaper, the same, or more expensive, depending on exact circumstances. You can't assume this about performance. I've seen queries in Oracle sped up 50x by turning an `in` into a `join`, though it wasn't a flat list of constants like yours.

Comment: The `order by case ... complex expression here ...` will probably be the costly part, since it wont allow indexes to be used, forcing a final sort step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IN clause is more readable than the inner join. So it is a good idea to make this change as to increase readablility. The optimizer should treat the two queries just the same, if it is any good :-)

The query is obviously made to rank the 100+ publisher IDs by their retailer. It is quite rare to only return the publisher IDs, but well, we don't know what's done with the result of course. Obviously the app only needs the IDs ordered by retailer rank.

**UPDATE: I had errors in the following part that are now corrected thanks to joop.**

You can increase readability further:

```
case r.sector_id when r.sector_id then 1 else 2 end
```

is simply

```
case when r.sector_id is null then 2 else 1 end
```

Same for

```
case (r.poi_sector_id) when r.poi_sector_id then 3 else 4 end
```

which is

```
case when r.poi_sector_id is null then 4 else 3 end
```

A strange way of writing this. May even be a mistake.

The `CASE` expressions sort nulls after non-nulls, so we could just as well use

```
order by r.sector_id is null, p.seo_frontpage_factor, r.poi_sector_id is null, p.id
```

as PostgreSQL sorts `false` before `true` (same as MySQL by the way).

Comment: So this might have little or no improvement only increases readability  ..

Comment: Yes, that's correct. But readability is worth a lot. It makes your query easier to maintain.

Comment: Shouldnt it be `COALESCE(NULLIF(r.sector_id,1),2)` ? (which of course is *very* ugly)

Comment: @joop: No. `r.sector_id` always equals itself, except for when it's null. So `case r.sector_id when r.sector_id then 1 else 2 end` merely replaces a null with a 2.

Comment: And your version replaces a non-null value by itself (which can be <> 1)

Comment: I told you it would be ugly!

Comment: "*sort nulls after non-nulls*" - unless you use `NULLS FIRST` in the `order by` expression (MySQL does not have a `boolean` type by the way)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: You are being confused. `case when r.sector_id is null then 2 else 1 end` sorts nulls after non-nulls, no matter whether you add `NULLS LAST` or not. As to MySQL: while `BOOLEAN` is considered a numeric data type there, you can still use it as in  `WHERE is_valid`; so I wouldn't say they don't have a boolean type.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: you can also use `where 'foo'` and MySQL accepts that as a "valid" where condition. Or even `where 'true'` - which in fact is the same as `where 1=0`

Comment: What I actually meant is: you can simplify `order by case when r.sector_id is null then 2 else 1 end` to `order by r.sector_id nulls last`

Comment: @ThorstenKettner could you  please update the answer with final query and details

Comment: I've just altered the `ORDER BY` clause to `order by r.sector_id is null, p.seo_frontpage_factor, r.poi_sector_id is null, p.id`. But as mentioned: it is strange to see the obfuscated `is null` check in the original query. This may indicate a mistake and that it was supposed to order differently. Also: have you checked your app to see why it needs the publisher IDs ordered thus?